# What is the relationship between W, X, Y and P, M retinal ganglion cells?

Tags: physiology, vision, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, histology

In *Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology (12e)* the retinal ganglion cells (RGCs) are classified into W, X, and Y types. However, in *[Gray's Anatomy (40<sup>th</sup> ed.)](http://www.us.elsevierhealth.com/gray-anatomy/gray-anatomy-expert-consult/9780443066849/)*, RGS are subdivided into midget and parasol cells. What is the relationship between the W-X-Y versus midget-parasol classifications?

Summary of the WXY classification as in *Medical Physiology*:

About 40% ganglion cells are W cells. They are the smallest (<10 μm), and the slowest (8 m/s) to transmit signals, but they have the broadest receptive field. They receive signals from rods and detect directional movement.

About 55% are X cells. They have medium size (10~15 μm) and transmission speed (14 m/s). Their fields are small. They transmit color vision.

About 5% are Y cells. They are the largest (<35 μm) and the fastest (35 m/s) to transmit signals. They have broad fields. They respond to rapid changes in the vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
X = P = midget = β
Y = M = parasol = α
W = γ

**Background**
First off, P and M cells are not equal to parasol and midget cells; on the contrary - P cells are midgets and M cells are considered to be parasols.

**X**, **Y** and **W cells** are used to denote different [retinal ganglion cells](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ii-anatomy-and-physiology-of-the-retina/ganglion-cell-physiology/) in cats, as proposed by experiments [Enroth-Gubel & Robson (1966)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1395960/). As you already indicate, these cells have different physiological response properties. X and Y cells have the standard [**center-surround**](http://hubel.med.harvard.edu/book/b9.htm) distribution of their receptive field, X cells having linear additive response properties in center and surround and Y cells nonlinear properties. X cells therefore have predictive responses such that responses can be predicted to be maximal (e.g. light shining on the ON center and no light stimulation on the OFF surround). Y cells tend to respond in more complex ways. W cells do not have a center-surround structure [(Bruce *et al*, 1996)](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ii-anatomy-and-physiology-of-the-retina/ganglion-cell-physiology/).

Based on morphology, retinal ganglion cells in the cat have been labelled **α**, **β** and **γ cells**, which are thought to correspond to the physiological classes of **Y**, **X** and **W** cells, respectively [(Boycott & H. Wässle, 1974)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1331022/).

The **P** and **M** division was introduced by [De Monasterio & Gouras (1975)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1348381/) based on monkey experiments. P and M refer to the **parvocellular** and **magnocellular** connections retinal ganglion cells in monkeys make in the [LGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_geniculate_nucleus) of the brain. Both types of cells have a center-surround receptive field structure like X and Y cells in the  cat. P cells show **color opponency** and respond to specific wavelengths of light, and are involved in color vision. P cells respond to a **range of wavelengths** and respond most vigorous when different light intensities illuminate the center and surround [(Bruce *et al*, 1996)](http://www.tandf.net/books/details/9781841692388/).

**P cells** are considered to be mostly **midget** ganglion cells, and equivalent to **β cells** of cat. **M cells**, on the other hand are considered to be mostly **parasol cells** and resembling **α cells** [(Kolb, 2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11535/#ch07gc1.EXTYLES.7).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Boycott & H. Wässle, *J Physiol* (1974); **240**(2): 397–419](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1331022/)

**-** [Bruce *et al*, Visual Perception (1996); 3<sup>rd</sup> ed. Psychology Press](http://www.tandf.net/books/details/9781841692388/)

**-** [De Monasterio & Gouras, *J Physiol* (1975); **251**(1): 167–95](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1348381/)

**-** [Enroth-Gubel & Robson, *J Physiol* (1966); **187**(3): 517–52](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1395960/)

**-** [Kolb H. Webvision (2001). Salt Lake City (UT): University of Utah Health Sciences Center](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11535/#ch07gc1.EXTYLES.7)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

According to *Comparative Vertebrate Neuroanatomy*, the XYW classfication is used for cat retina. They roughly correspond to the M, P, K cells in primates, respectively.